# I need a VBA algorithm that will give me all combinations for totaling mony on multiple recordsrecords

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has 6 records in it.  Each record has an amount field.  I need to write a process to give me a total amount for every possible combination of rows.  For Example

```
Total = row1 amount
Total = row2 amount
Total = row3 amount
Total = row4 amount
Total = row5 amount
Total = row6 amount
Total = row1 amount + row2 amount
Total = row1 amount + row3 amount
Total = row1 amount + row4 amount
Total = row1 amount + row5 amount
Total = row1 amount + row6 amount
Total = row1 amount + row2 amount + row3 amount
Total = row1 amount + row2 amount + row4 amount
```

etc.

Does anyone have an algorithm or code example that will do this?

Comment: Just to be sure, you want 6! different results? At least I think that is the math...

Comment: Also, what have you tried? Do you have any code done yourself? Check out [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help us help you!

Comment: #PartyHatPanda -- No I believe it would be like 63, total possible combinations for 6 records.  I want every possible combination that, in this case, 6 records can generate. I haven't tried anything yet because I just can't get it straight in my head how it should work.

Comment: Yes you are right, I only got 63 values running it. Try using nested for loops and an array to hold the individual sums.

Comment: #PartyHatPanda -- I want my code to be dynamic enough to run  for any number of records.  This example has 6 records, another account may only have 2 records, another may have 15 records.  I need to figure out dynamically how to created the loops.

Answer (score 0):

***Background:***

You need to know about [permutation and combination](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~wgreen4/Math124S07/PermuCombinations.pdf) in order to define what are you exactly going for. By the context given I assume you need combination.

***Solution approach:***

Given the main topic approach, there are plenty of topics that give an approach to that, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078363/permutations-in-vba-excel) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780016/vba-write-all-possible-combinations-of-4-columns-of-data) are examples in stackoverflow database. I do not find useful just to copy paste the code form their answers nor write it explicitly for you just to copy paste.

***Further advices:***

There are plenty of templates designed for this matter, [this is a good one to modify to your needs](http://excelnegocios.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Generar-Permutaciones-Combinaciones-en-Excel.xls), however the interface is in spanish