# Having problems permutating an matrix in vba (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I believe the problem is in the second for because of the differences between c# and vba but I'm not 100% sure so any and all help would be appreciated.

Literally everything

```
    kraj = False
    j = 0
    While kraj = False
        For i = 0 To 6 Step 1
            Cells(1, "A") = output(i, stacks(i))
            j = j + 1
        Next i

        For i = 0 To 6 Step 1
            stacks(i) = stacks(i) + 1
            If (stacks(i) = 3) Then
                If (i = 0) Then
                    kraj = True
                Else
                    stacks(i) = 0
                End If
            Else

            End If
        Next i


    Wend
```

This is working code in C#

```
int[] ics = new int[7];
bool end = false;
int number_of_lines = 0;

while (!end)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(output[i][ics[i]]);

        if (i / 6 == 1) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(); number_of_lines++; 
        }
    }

    for (int i = ics.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ics[i]++;

        if (ics[i] == output[i].Length)
            if (i == 0) 
                end = true;
            else 
                ics[i] = 0;
        else 
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please take a moment to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear problem statement, the output you expect, the output you receive, the difference between the two, where you are stuck, and what you have done to try to resolve the problem.

Comment: Did you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29078363/4717755)

Comment: i tried correcting it

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do? What are output and stacks? One guess could be that you are trying to write data from an array to a range on a worksheet. You should edit your question and put this information inside it. Showing part of the desired result might also help.

Comment: Hi, you need to show how all variables and arrays are declared and filled.

Answer (score 0):

## Array Example

This example demonstrates the use of 1-based arrays which can be pasted (deposited) into a range in one go (see last line of code).

```
Sub ArrayExample()

  Const cLngRow As Long = 7         ' Array Number of Rows
  Const cIntColumn As Integer = 3   ' Array Number of Columns
  Const cStrFirst As String = "A1"  ' Target First Cell Range

  Dim vntEx As Variant  ' Array
  Dim i As Long         ' Array Row Counter
  Dim j As Integer      ' Array Column Counter

  ' Resize Array
  ReDim vntEx(1 To cLngRow, 1 To cIntColumn)

  ' Write to array.
  For i = 1 To cLngRow
    For j = 1 To cIntColumn
      vntEx(i, j) = i * j
    Next
  Next

  ' Print array to Immediate window
  For i = 1 To cLngRow
    For j = 1 To cIntColumn
      Debug.Print vntEx(i, j)
    Next
  Next

  ' Paste array into Worksheet. You don't have to loop.
  Range(cStrFirst).Resize(UBound(vntEx, 1), UBound(vntEx, 2)) = vntEx

End Sub
```

Comment: I need to insert the permutations of the matrix and not the actual matrix

Comment: Zoran Vidovic: This is just an example how to handle arrays and loops in VBA. Your question is not clear enough to write an answer, yet.